# Using jQuery to load new image into div with a different folder path

Tags: jquery, image, path

Here is my set up:

I have two folders for images, 640 and 1024.  I'll have images displayed on a page that are from the 640 folder and named 001,002,003 etc etc.

When you click an image, it loads the larger sized image into a div, which is located in 1024.  Each image in 1024 will have the same name as the smaller image in 640.

Does this make sense?  I tried to write my own code, but it just wasn't working.

Thanks for the help.

**Code**

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('#load').load(function() {
        var imageFolder = 'images/2500/';
        $(this).each(function () {
            imageName = $(this).attr('alt');
            $(this).attr('src', imageFolder + imageName);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Post your code here so that we can have a look

Comment: If you show us the code you're written and tell us why it doesn't work we'll be better able to help you. It's why we're here, *group hug!*

Comment: I have to create an in depth sentence to allow my comment of only 7 letters to post... 'posted'

Comment: Yea, we're gonna need to look at your `alt` tag...that almost sounded wrong...

Comment: You lost me.  I am new at this.  sort of pieced it together from other codes.

Comment: @Ryan - you're using `$(this).attr('alt');` to grab the `alt` attribute from your `<img src="" alt="" />` tag, which you then append to you `imageFolder` string. I'm just wondering if that `alt` tag in fact exists in your code, or if it has a value that's useful, as your code needs it :)

Comment: It didn't have it, but it still doesn't work.  Gahh.  No idea what I am doing.

Comment: If a code can be written so I can see it exactly and learn what I am missing/doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, awesome, I'll try post my 'best-way-I'd-do-this' solution below, but in future just throw out as much code as is relevant and we can definitely help :)

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I don't know if it's possible to do without adding an alt tag to the image. But i'd like to keep the image tag with just the source.  i'd like the jquery to find the same named image in just a different folder and create that new image code into the #load div.  basically ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as promised, here's my 'best-way-I'd-do-this' solution, freely open to crit and comments. I'm also going to try and base this as closely as possible to your code so that you can see how the elements relate to each other.

I have no idea which `img` your adding the click to, or what `#load` points to. The `.load()` function in jQuery also needs a URL to load, which seems to be missing.

I'm going to assume, from your question, that you have a bunch of images on your page, and when you click on one of them their larger counterpart will be displayed in a `div` below them. Hope this is accurate. First, let's start with the HTML:

```
<div class="small_images_container">
    <img src="/images/640/001.jpg" />
    <img src="/images/640/002.jpg" />
    <img src="/images/640/003.jpg" />
    ...
</div>

<div id="big_image_container"></div>
```

So we have some images, and we have a container to put the bigger one in, awesome. Now for the script, which needs to add the click events as well as fetch the bigger image and put it into the `.big_image_container`...I'm not worried about the `alt` tag in this solution, and rather I'm going to break up the original `src` attributes with Javascript's `.split()` function and grab the image's filename that way...here we go:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.small_images_container img').click(function(){

            // get the image and its 'src' attribute...
            var image = $(this);
            var src = image.attr('src');

            // split the 'src' attribute with the '/' character and get the
            // last element in the array...
            src = src.split('/');
            var filename = src[src.length-1];

            // now we can create the image we're going to put in the
            // large image container...
            var image_folder = '/images/1024/';
            var large_image = $('<img />');
            large_image.attr('src', image_folder + filename);

            // set the HTML of the container to the new image...
            // first, clear out whatever HTML was in there, then add
            // the new image...
            $('#big_image_container').html('');
            $('#big_image_container').append(large_image);

        });

    });

</script>
```

I hope this makes sense and helps! Please let me know if I've missed something, or if something is unclear!

Comment: Chris, this works perfectly.  It's written in a way I can totally understand and learn from.  Is "var filename = src[src.length-1];" this what's gets the actual image name? 001.jpg, 002.jpg?

Comment: That's correct...the `.split()` function will basically create an array like `['images', '640', '001.jpg']` for example, and you'll get the last element of that array with the code above...

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js">      </script>
<title>Loading...</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/640/error_latest_dump_restore.png"/>
<script>
var smallFolder = '640';
var bigFolder = '1024';
$('img').click(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).attr('src');
    var tmp1 = tmp.replace(smallFolder, bigFolder);
    $(this).attr("src",tmp1);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was thinking about that...but what happens if the image name is `640.jpg` for example?